# Update manager and sudo apt-get give the following message" E: The method Driver/usr/lib/apt/methods/http// could not be found

Tags: updates

Tried both the Update manager and terminal, get the same message.
Removed and re-downloaded Update manager, same message.

Answer (score 1):

Check your software source, somewhere you are using `http//:` instead of `http://`